# How to install aws-cli in docker container based on maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14 image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

I would like to install aws-cli for below images but I received below error. I tried with apk, apt but none of then did not work. Can you please help how should I update my dockerfile?

I do not want to change my base image, I need to use `maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14`.

```
sh: apt-get: command not found
```

---

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y vim jq unzip curl \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \

    #install aws 2
    RUN curl --silent --show-error --fail "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
      unzip awscliv2.zip && \
      ./aws/install && \
      rm -rf awscliv2.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker image `maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14` is based on Oracle Linux which uses `rpm` to manage packages, so `apt-get` is not available.

```
docker run -i -t maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14 -- cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: thanks @gogo..I received as error below.. How should I use rpm to install packages ?
 Step 14/21 : RUN rpm -ivh unzip-6.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
 ---> Running in 685279bbf10c
[91merror: open of unzip-6.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c rpm -ivh unzip-6.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: `rpm -iv https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/unzip-6.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm`